# Set workbook view with openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Is it possible to set the Workkbook View to "Page Layout" with openpyxl? Looking on stackoverflow and the openpyxl docs I can't seem to find it. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to set the view to `pageLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible with this code:**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

#Value must be one of {'pageBreakPreview', 'pageLayout', 'normal'}
ws.sheet_view.view = "pageLayout"
```

**How did I find out?**

To my surprise I also could not find any tutorials or anything in the docs on this topic.
I did a little digging and if you type into the terminal:

```
print(ws.sheetview)
```

A series of parameters will pop out, including the one we are looking for (the `view` attribute):

```
Parameters:
windowProtection=None, showFormulas=None, showGridLines=None, showRowColHeaders=None, showZeros=None, rightToLeft=None, tabSelected=None, showRuler=None, showOutlineSymbols=None, defaultGridColor=None, showWhiteSpace=None, veSymbols=None, defaultGridColor=None, showWhiteSpace=None, view=None, topLeftCell=None, colorId=None, zoomScale=None, zoomScaleNormal=None, zoomScaleSheetLayoutViewalePageLayoutNone,ne, selection=[<openpyxl.worksheet.views.S=None, zoomScalePageLayoutView=None, zoomToFit=None, workbookViewId=0, pane=None, selection=[<openpyxl.worksheet.views.Selection object>
```

You can then set this attribute according to the code on the top of the answer to the three predetermined values otherwise you will get an `ValueError: Value must be one of {'pageBreakPreview', 'pageLayout', 'normal'}`.

Comment: Please leave thumbs up if the answer helped you!