# Visible excel mode with openpyxl<2.6.0> python<3.7.5>

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Is there a way to make excel visible with openpyxl module in python 3.7.5?
Did some reasearch on documentation and other resources but did not find any answer.
*https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.6/api/openpyxl.workbook.properties.html*

```
openpyxl.__version__
> '2.6.0'
```

My objective is to obtain the same result as with use of `win32com.client`

```
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
```

Tried setting `visibility = 'visible' and minimized=False` within parameters of `openpyxl.workbook.views.BookView object`

Also tried setting different parameters within 'sheetview' as specified in this topic:
*[Set workbook view with openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040268/set-workbook-view-with-openpyxl)*
Yet with no success. I believe that there is possibility to do so but i couldnt dig to the answer.
Would appreciate getting some help with the package as documentation does not include detailed descriptions.

Comment: What do you mean "visible"?

Comment: Like specified in question. Same result as win32com gives